# touchesBegan doesn't work with UIImageView animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, touchesbegan

I'm having some issues over here. I've got a method called

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

for a `UIImageView`, it works fine while the image is static, the `touchesBegan` method gets called... but when I make the `UIImageView` animated, `touchesBegan` stop working.
Any ideas of why this happens?

Comment: I solved this using UITapGestureRecognizer   http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive touchesBegan during animations you must include the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` animation option when creating your animation. There is a good discussion [here](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/64569-uiview-animatewithduration-blocks-the-screen-for-touch-input.html) about it.